# Cannot start session without errors in phpMyAdmin running Nginx with PHP-FPM

Tags: centos, nginx, php-fpm

Whenever I open phpMyAdmin from my VPS I get the following error:

> Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.

I have researched it, but cant seem to find a solution, I have done the following:

- Cleared cache and cookies
- Checked the php.ini (see below)
- Checked the logs (found nothing relevant)
- Given the correct permissions. [by `sudo chown -R root:nginx /home/humza/pma`]

I am running Nginx with PHP-FPM, I have php-mysql and all that working fine but I can't get phpMyAdmin to work. I downloaded it off phpMyAdmin's website and extracted it, that's all.

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6n57cW8H - my php.ini sessions bit

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VaNP2TLi - my whole php.ini

None of my logs have anything relevant. My error logs have other PHP errors but not this one and my access logs don't have anything either.

I have checked my nginx logs and my PHP-FPM logs.

I tried installing phpMyAdmin via yum and got a whole lot of dependency errors.

```
[root@infinity ~]# yum install phpmyadmin
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:2.11.11.3-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-mcrypt >= 4.1.0 for package: phpMyAdmin
--> Processing Dependency: php >= 4.1.0 for package: phpMyAdmin
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 4.1.0 for package: phpMyAdmin
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.i386 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php
---> Package php-mbstring.i386 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php-mbstring
---> Package php-mcrypt.i386 0:5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 for package: php-mcrypt
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.i386 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php
---> Package php-cli.i386 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php-cli
---> Package php-mbstring.i386 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php-mbstring
---> Package php-mcrypt.i386 0:5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 for package: php-mcrypt
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
php-mbstring-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-mbstring-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
php-mcrypt-5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1.i386 from extras has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 is needed by package php-mcrypt-5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1.i386 (extras)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 is needed by package php-mcrypt-5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1.i386 (extras)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-mbstring-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
[root@infinity ~]#
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"
```

Does the user account PHP is running under have read/write permissions on this directory?

Comment: What is the php-fpm user called, or is it just nginx?

Comment: The folder /var/lib/php/session didnt exist, I have added the permissions, created the folder and restarted php-fpm and nginx. Still not working.

Comment: I have it working now, I just have another problem now : http://serverfault.com/questions/262293/php-mcrypt-installation.

Comment: Great, I had a similar problem as TS, however this method worked for me. I have been pounding my head literary for hours and hours. Why is there no good list of prerequsetst.