# PHP-Mcrypt Installation

Tags: php, centos, nginx, php-fpm

I need to install php-mcrypt on my CentOS 5.5 VPS, When I try yum install php-mcrypt, it says that it is set to be updated which implies that it is already installed. I looked in the /usr/lib/php/modules and cant find the .so file.

Anyway I want to update it but yum is giving the following error, I am running PHP-FPM on Nginx.

```
Last login: Thu Apr 21 12:13:30 2011 from cpc2-seve18-2-0-cust438.13-3.cable.virginmedia.com
[root@infinity ~]# yum install php-mcrypt
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.i386 0:5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 for package: php-mcrypt
--> Processing Dependency: php >= 5.1.6 for package: php-mcrypt
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.i386 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php
---> Package php-mcrypt.i386 0:5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 for package: php-mcrypt
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.i386 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php
---> Package php-cli.i386 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php-cli
---> Package php-mcrypt.i386 0:5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 for package: php-mcrypt
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-mcrypt-5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1.i386 from extras has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 is needed by package php-mcrypt-5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1.i386 (extras)
php-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 is needed by package php-mcrypt-5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1.i386 (extras)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
[root@infinity ~]#
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the output of yum repolist

Comment: http://pastebin.com/X9jFvWKW

Comment: Maybe you are trying to install the wrong version of mcrypt.  On my server I had to use `php53u-mcrypt`, for example.

Comment: I'm still looking for a credible solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you maybe have some excludes in `/etc/yum.conf`?

Run:

```
yum --disableexcludes=all install php-mcrypt
```

But be careful before you accept!

Cheers

Comment: Nope, nothing is excluded.  http://pastebin.com/EvQkRX4f

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `yum clean all` ?
I've found that that can sometimes be helpful when yum seems confused.

Also try the following to make sure soemone has not inadvertently installed RPMSs of the wrong architecture - it's a long shot, but i've seen it happen

```
rpm -qa --qf %{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}-%{ARCH}\\n |grep php
```